# Get ISO 3166-2 Code from HERE Geocoder API

Tags: here-api, iso-3166

Is there a way to get the [ISO 3166-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2) Code for a specific PostalCode/CountryCode Combination with the [HERE Geocoder API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/)?

Per Example:
1210/AT => AT-9

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the HERE Geocoder does not expose this information in the response.